# OData using $select with asp.net core throws System.ArgumentException

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core, odata

**Query**: `$filter=DatetimeLocal gt 2021-03-19T12:50:54.219Z&$select=OrganizationId`

**Error**: System.ArgumentException: Value type of serializer is Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Query.Expressions.PropertyContainer+NamedProperty`1[[System.String, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]] and does not match member type Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Query.Expressions.PropertyContainer. (Parameter 'serializer')

I've used this tutorial in order to implement OData: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/webapi/first-odata-api

What could be the issue?

Answer (score -2):

The Query should be in this format `?$filter=CreatedDate gt 2021-03-22T10:39:35Z`

Comment: what about the select? I need the select, and that's the issue

Comment: ?$filter=CreatedDate gt 2021-03-22T10:39:35Z&$select=PropA is working for me . issue is some dll missing on your side . @GeraldHughes

Comment: What versions do you use? How did you configure odata please?